# Не удается скомпилировать проект в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

При попытке выдает:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

С Юнити работаю недавно. Поэтому возможно ошибка и глупая.

Comment: Вам написали файлы с ошибками и даже строчки в этих файлах с ошибками, вы текст, что привели, сами то читали?

Comment: @tym32167, это файлы самой Unity, не думаю, что в этом стоит искать проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться советами из ответов, которые были даны на подобный вопрос:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194428/unityeditor-buildplayerwindowbuildmethodexception

а) Открыть **File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Publishing Settings** и установить галочку в поле "use legacy SDK tools".

б) Удалить папку "Plugins" из папки "Assets" (если таковая имеется)